# How can I adjust floating window/dialog box behaviour in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, workspaces

I've noticed that dialogue boxes (such as the save dialogue box which appears in a browser when you download a file) cannot be moved beyond the edges of the workspace in which they appear; they are stuck within the workspace in which they appear until they are closed.

This is really inconvenient because there are times when we'd like to put them aside for a bit without closing them. Is there a setting/extension that lets you adjust this behaviour? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are modal dialog boxes. They are special windows that are connected to a parent window.

You can change the behaviour of the modal dialog with gnome-tweaks in the window-settings box.

Another thing you can do to see also the bottom of a dialog is to move the window with the pointer (mouse) while the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed.

I have trouble reading some texts so I zoom the texts (with the accessibility control panel) but that results in the dialog box being to big for the monitor... I think that this is a (window manager) bug??

Comment: That worked for the dialogue windows, but some floating windows are still stuck, for example, if you check out this application: pureref.com it is always stuck in the current workspace, if you know something that could help please let me know, else I'd accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I think it's only related to the 20.04 as mentioned here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2124

The quick fix is:
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I noticed the issue. Today I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately the always center modal dialog behavior is a big no to me. I have a 24" large monitor and I frequently open and switch between multiple programs. Forcing the dialog center on it's parent window disables my ability to 'peek' the thing behind it really slows down my performance of using computer.

I am sure there should be ways to disable the behavior because that's just bad. The best solution for me was I removed Ubuntu 20.04 immediately and switched back to Ubuntu Mate. The default Ubuntu Mate installation just works even without any change of the settings.

Comment: You can do that with the Tweaks app. You can get this buy the command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`. The setting you are looking in the Windows tab and is called center new windows

Comment: Try the solution in the answer, because ubuntu 20.04 is just so fluid, it's probably the best distro until now